# Why do I need to spread the object to pass it down as a prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-props

I saw this code in a tutorial:

```
tours.map(tour => {
  return <Tour key={tour.id} {...tour}/>;
})
```

Tours is just an array of objects. I'm beginner to react, and as I understand, "tour" object is passed down as a prop to the  component. However, I don't understand why do you have to individually pass all key-property values with the spread operator, why can't you just pass down the whole object? 

Also why there is no need to define a name? Like: <Tour greet = {'hello'} />

Comment: That also simplified format. And while executing running JSX convert to JS. [See this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html). Finally all props convert into key value object

Answer (score 0):

This basically is to provide simplicity to your code writing in ES6, and react adopted the same, please find below an example to understand the concept.
Also reg **key**, we should use it avoid react throwing **missing key issue** exception
// simple example

```
function App() {
 return <Hello firstName="Minh" lastName="Nguyen" />;
}
// another example with spread operator
function App() {
  const props = {firstName: 'Minh', lastName: 'Nguyen'};
  return <Hello {...props} />;
 }`
```